# How do I translate, "For every movie, at least two students have seen it" into predicate logic? The second part is difficult.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, predicate-logic

I need to express the following into predicate logic:
"For every movie, there are at least two different students who have seen it."

The following predicates are given and assumed:

- D(x) is true exactly when x is a student
- M(x) is true exactly when x is a movie
- S(x,y) is true exactly when x has seen y

I've done some "studying" and research and came to a couple conclusions. First, it seems that this problem will require is two Existential Quantifiers for the two different students and a single Universal Quantifier for every movie.

My first impressions were to structure it this way:

- ∃x∃y : There exists a student x and a student y
- ∃x∃y(∀xM(x) ∧ D(x) ∧ D(y) → S(x,y) x ≠ y) : There exists a student x and a student y where for all movies and a student D(x) and student D(y) have seen it where and x is not equal to y.

However, when reading it through the S(x,y) is confusing as in assumed predicates, x has seen y. So, in the logic I wrote above it's read as "student x has seen student y" I think. I'm not sure if I'm on the right track or if I'm completely wrong. Any help or clarification is greatly appreciated.

Comment: "at least two" means that there is $x$ and there is $y$ and $x \ne y$

Comment: So "For every movie, there are at least two different students who have seen it" must be: "For every z (if Movie (z), then there is x and there is y such that Dtudent (x) and Dtudent (y) and x ≠ y and Seen (x,z) and Seen (y,z))".

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Ok so it seems I got that portion correct. However, I'm confused on how that applies to S(x,y). Wouldn't the y be the movie? As in the assumed predicates, x has seen y. Thus, some student x has seen some movie y?